# Draw a triangle using java

Tags: java

I need to write a isosceles triangle with customer height and width.

triangle(5, 10);  draws ok. 
triangle(10, 10); draws ok.
triangle(10, 5);  draws ok. but with triangle(6, 10) I have a problem. How can I avoid this problem ? What do you advise?

The problem is that not all necessary points draw.

My code is below.

```
public class triangle1 {
    static  int num1 =0;
    public static void triangle(int height, int width) { 

      /*  double num = new BigDecimal((double)width/2/height).setScale(1, RoundingMode.DOWN).doubleValue();*/
        double num = (double) width/2/height;
      //  System.out.print(num);
        triangle(height, width, 0,0.0, num);
    }

    private static void triangle(int height, int width, int s, double amountfordivide, double num) {

        System.out.println(s+" "+ amountfordivide+ " " + num+" "+ (++num1));
        if (s++ <= height ) {
            triangle(height, width, s, amountfordivide+num, num);
          //  System.out.println();
        /*System.out.println(n +" "+ m);*/
            if (s-1 == 0) {
                for (double i = 0.0; i <= width; i = i + num) {
                    System.out.print(".");
                }
                System.out.println();
            } else  {
                for (double i = 0.0; i <= width; i = i+num) {
                    if (i == amountfordivide)  System.out.print( ".");
                    else if (i == (width - amountfordivide)) System.out.print(".");
                    else
                        System.out.print(" ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        triangle(10, 5);
    }

}
```

Comment: But you did not explain what problem you have

Comment: What the problem you're having? Vertices aren't working or what?

Comment: the problem is that not all necessary points draws

Comment: What does the variable `s` represent?

Comment: calculates height of point

Comment: Its not a good idea to do arithmetic operations with both int and double in the same expression. Your for loops should use int for the iterator, not double

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not think that adding doubles will reach some exact value. Therefore,

```
 for (double i = 0.0; i <= width; i = i+num) {
```

must be written

```
 for (double i = 0.0; i <= width + num/2.0; i = i+num) {
```

But then you have the problem that you compare doubles using ==

```
 if (i == amountfordivide)  System.out.print( ".");
 else if (i == (width - amountfordivide)) System.out.print(".");
```

You might use a similar "bracketing comparison,

```
 if( amountfordivide - num/2.0 < i && i < amountfordivide + num/2.0 )
```

and the same for the other condition.

But it would be best to change the calculaton so that you do the loops using int loop counters and "hot" values (amountfordivide).

Comment: yes its good idea to use only int without any double. i need only increase scale. all genius ideas are simple.

Comment: This is standard practice. Even when you do need double values, avoid add, e.g., when computing abscissa values for numeric integration you use x = a + i*h rather than x = a, and repeatedly x += h.